# Почему компилятор C# генерирует такой код IL для возврата значения

Tags: c#, компилятор, cil

Ассоциация: [stackoverflow.com/q/26323373/6677992](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26323373/6677992).

Простая программа, метод принимающий 1 аргумент и тут же его отдающий (режим компилятора- без оптимизации).

```
void Main()
{
    var b = false;
    Method(b);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public bool Method(bool a){
    return a;
}
```

Инструкции на языке IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // b
IL_0003:  ldarg.0     
IL_0004:  ldloc.0     // b
IL_0005:  call        UserQuery.Method
IL_000A:  pop         
IL_000B:  ret         

Method:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  br.s        IL_0005
IL_0005:  ldloc.0     
IL_0006:  ret
```

**Вопрос:** почему `IL_0004` отсутствует? И вытекающий из этого вопрос — почему происходит перенаправление на `IL_0005`?

Comment: @Jagailo Нет, вопрос был именно почему отсутствует `IL_0004`, и вытекающий из него почему происходит перенаправление на `IL_0005`?

Comment: Вижу, что вы всё-таки подсели на linqpad :) Не забывайте, что в настройках можно отключить "компилировать с/без оптимизации"

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26323373/2881286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Перевод ответа @flindeberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26323424/6677992)

Эта ветка предназначена для целей отладки, возвращаемое значение было рассчитано и сохранено, и теперь отладчик может быть «вызван». То же самое с `NOP` в записи метода.

Что касается `IL_0004`, `br.s` имеет адрес и он не помещается в «одну строку», один байт здесь (я не знаю, насколько вы знакомы с адресацией, но одна инструкция обычно представляет собой один байт, то есть 8-разрядный, а также адрес или смещение, обычно 8-, 16- или 32-разрядный. В этом случае у нас есть 8-битный код операции с 8-разрядным смещением. В Википедии есть [хорошая статья о CIL-OP-кодах](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions)).

Кроме того, предположим, что ваш метод имеет несколько возвратов и через, например, if-ветви, все они переходят в конец, `IL_0005` в вашем случае, поэтому требуется только одна точка останова при возврате функции.

---

От себя хочу добавить- если включить режим оптимизации для компилятора, получаем следующие инструкции:

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // b
IL_0002:  ldarg.0     
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // b
IL_0004:  call        UserQuery.Method
IL_0009:  pop         
IL_000A:  ret         

Method:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  ret
```

Как мы видим, в данном случае в методе происходит просто загрузка аргумента в стек и возврат из метода. Как заметил [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26325240/6677992) в этом же вопросе- это очень распространенный артефакт парсера рекурсивного спуска, который использует компилятор C#.

Comment: >> (я не знаю, насколько вы знакомы с адресацией... Вы просто копипастите ответ с друго сайта? Через 6 минут после написания вопроса? Ради рейтинга чтоли

Comment: @Jagailo На момент написания вопроса я не подозревал что есть ответ на SO. Кроме того, почему нет? Тем более согласно [этому ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4769/218976) подобное приветствуется на этом сайте.

Comment: @Anamnian _запостите его под своим же вопросом, **указав, что это перевод**_ - сейчас source в конце ответа мало заметна, и сразу непонятно на какой именно источник указывает - другой сайт, другой ответ здесь